# Flash Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, object, reference, null

I've been stuck with such an error for 2 days now, and however I search on solving this from the number of previous questions asked about this error, I still can't seem to get it to work, mainly because I don't understand it at all.

Every time I enter the door with a hittest to the next scene, the error goes:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at gallerycopy_fla::MainTimeline/collision()
```

The code's pretty long so I'm just gonna put the FLA (CS5) file here: http://www.mediafire.com/?129c41thb1u38c4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple... 
the function collision() is not accessible after frame 4 because of the blank frame, but the EnterFrame still calls it.
One way to solve it is to extract the L1_actions layer to frame 10 (and delete the black keyframe)
or rather cancel the enterframe event on frame 4:

```
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,collission)
```

Do whatever is best for you project.

And small advice, what you did shows great talent, I would suggest you to stop coding on the timeline and move to coding using some code editor (flash builder \ flashdevelop etc)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. :D 

But then, I tried doing this to another room (removing the function of the previous scene), and the error this time came from the active event listener of that scene which was supposed to be active.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (stage)
{
    init();
}
else
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

public function init():void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}
```

if its flash cs5 remove moveclips from frame 2 (if 'export in frame 1' is unchecked).